# VSTS Build Succeeded even ARM Template was invalid

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

Am working on Azure Resource Manager Templates(ARM Templates) and VSTS CI&CD. With the help of ARM Templates, I want to deploy AKS (Azure kubernete Service). So before going to deploy, I need to validate my ARM Template in the CI-Build by applying a PowerShell task. But here, at the time of validating my ARM Template “It’s not stopping CI-Build even when the validation fails”. Its giving output as “Validation Completed” as shown in the below picture . Is there any solution to resolve this issue, i.e. I wanted to stop my CI-Build running if any validation fails.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how does your powershell script look like. But according to the screenshot, the powershell script is executed successfully without any error code return. You can update your powershell script to check the validate result and set the exit code to "1" if the result is "InvalidTemplate". This will make the powershell task fail when the template is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the resource is defined multiple times in the template. You can remove it and its always a good practice from the PowerShell script to use `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` and validate if the template is valid and has obtained all its parameters and then deploy using `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Like Eddie said you can try this inside a `try{} catch` block and return an exception or an exit code to make the VSTS Build pipeline fail, if the script fails.